# Material-ui@next with typescript d.ts file

Tags: typescript, material-ui, definitelytyped, .d.ts

I tried to install material-ui definition files using @types/material-ui@next but the only versions available are to version 0. Is there any repository that I can download with d.ts files at version 1 of material-ui?

Comment: Good question. The latest version seems to have the .d.ts files embedded in the module. I had to uninstall any older mui @types modules in order for typescript to pick it up though. HTH

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my tsconfig:

```
"include": ["./node_modules/material-ui/src/**/*"],
```